# Google auth with passport callback not being reached

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, passport.js

Based on https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example/blob/master/server.js, I am trying to implement a basic Google auth using Passport and node.js.

My Passport configuration looks like this:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/callback" // not sure if correct.
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log("accessToken: " + accessToken);
    console.log("refreshToken: " + refreshToken);
    console.log("profile: " + profile);
    console.log("cb: " + cb);
    cb(accessToken, profile);
  }
));
```

I have set up the following GET routes:

```
app.get('/auth/',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log("success");
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

When I try to access the authentication page, I get a normal google login screen, but after I login, I get a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` message. The URL looks like `https://localhost:3000/auth/callback?code=ACCESS_CODE`, but is somehow not causing a redirect to `/login` (if it failed) or a redirect to `/` if it succeeded.

Any help is appreciated! I'm very new to Passport, and to oauth in general.

Answer (score 0):

According to [passport oauth2 library documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2), first parameter of passport middleware's callback is an error. So, your code:

```
cb(accessToken, profile)
```

is treated as errored with *accessToken* 'error'. That's probably an issue. You need to change it to:

```
cb(null, profile)
```